# Why do I get very large (100 percent) confidence intervals for predicted probabilities from logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confidence-interval, interaction, ggeffects

I performed this logistic model:

```
Model2i <- glm(Child ~ Age +Age2 + Education + `Place of residence` +`Marital status` + `Multiple birth`+ Region    + Period*`Conflict exposure` +`Sexual violence`+ `Child's death during war` * Period+`Sibling death during war`+ `Proportion of children died before 1996`, data=DATA2007_10km, weights  = Poids, family=binomial("logit")); summary(Model2i)
```

I want to plot predicted probabilities using `ggeffects` as follows:

```
ggpredict(Model2i, ci_level = 0.95,terms = c("Period","Conflict exposure")) %>% plot(connect.lines = TRUE)
```

but I get very large intervals for predicted probabilities as seen on the following picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAGgY.png)

I was expecting narrower prediction intervals. Can anyone tell me the cause of the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? It's hard to tell without any (toy) data that replicates your results. It could be that the result is correct and your data is "just bad" (or the model), or it could be a bug in the software.